# How to get the selected row item in XamDatagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, xamdatagrid

Below is my xaml

```
<Grid>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListBox x:Name="movieList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieMain.Movies}" Margin="10">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Label Content="Selected movie: " Margin="2" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=movieList}" />
</StackPanel>

<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" DataSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Artists, ElementName=movieList}">

<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
<igDP:FieldLayout>

<igDP:ComboBoxField Name="Name">
<igDP:ComboBoxField.EditorStyle>
<Style TargetType="igEditors:XamComboEditor">
<Setter Property="ItemsSource"
Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}}" />
</Style>
</igDP:ComboBoxField.EditorStyle>
</igDP:ComboBoxField>

<igDP:NumericField Name="Age" />

</igDP:FieldLayout>
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

</igDP:XamDataGrid>
</StackPanel>

<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="55" Height="25" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>

</Grid>
```

In above I bind Listbox with one model and based on selected item I am binding datagrid.

Now I am doing delete operation on datagrid. So how can I achieve the delete functionality?

I created a button for deleteing records. Can we pass command parameter for sleeted row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button ... Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDataItems[0], ElementName=dataGrid}" />
```

Comment: It's not working I am getting parameter as null. SelectedDataItems is not coming in intellisense as well